# How to echo. only if previous line is not empty?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, echo, batch-processing

How in my batch I can `echo.` ONLY if the previous line outputted is non-empty ? As you understood I want to avoid to have 2 /n/n

Comment: You have 11k rep, but your question looks like a 1rep. To answer your question: Don't echo an empty line if you already echoed an empty line

Comment: @jeb yes this i know of course, but when in the batch we have lot of function calling, lot of if, lot of goto, etc. it's hard to know if I already echoed an empty line :(

Comment: I would also suggest using `echo(` or `echo/` instead of `echo.` See [this post](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) for more details.

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_ and _batch-file_? Which of those shells are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function for `echo`, that remember if the last line was empty.

```
@echo off
call :func1
call :func2

:func1
call :echo "Func1"
call :echo ""
call :echo ""
exit /b

:func2
call :echo ""
call :echo "Func2"
exit /b

:echo
set "text=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!text!!last_line!" NEQ ""  (
  echo(!text!
)
endlocal
set "last_line=%~1"
exit /b
```

Output:

> Func1
>
> Func2